# PHP - Call external programs and show progress

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that takes the fields of a form to make 3 alternated program calls, where the output of the first one is the input of the second one and so on.

The problem is that I need to display the progress of each program call, nothing to complicated, I just like to show 3 different messages:

- System call N waiting.
- System call N in execution.
- System call N finished.

I´m trying to do that with the different PHP functions like exec(), popen() or proc_open() but with these ones the browser waits until each call finish.
The whole system calls don´t take more than 5 minutes, maybe 3 or 4, so, it would also be good to place a timer in each call, maybe 1.5 minutes, and if the call takes more that that time, kill the current system call, skip the following calls and show an error message.

Do you have any idea? Maybe a combination of ajax and javascript can be a solution. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
/*
  System Calls
  This file is required in another main script
  $projectPath and $projectName defined in the main script
*/

//$mainHome = getcwd();

$home = $projectPath . $projectName;
$temp = $home . "/temp/";
$calls = $temp . "CALLS";

$threads = array();

if(is_dir($temp)){
    //chdir($temp);
    $FILE = fopen($calls, "r");
    while(($call = fgetcsv($FILE)) !== FALSE) {
        //print_r($call);
        $threads[] = implode(" ", $call);
    }
}

//print_r($threads);

$descriptorspec = array(0 => array("pipe","r"),
                        1 => array("pipe","w"),
                        2 => array("file","./phpError.log","a")
);

for ($a=0; $a<count($threads); $a++) {
    print $threads[$a] . "<br/><br/>";
    exec($threads[$a])
    //$res = proc_open($threads[$a], $descriptorspec, $pipes, $temp);
}

//chdir($mainHome);
```

?>

Comment: Actually I only have a script that executes each call one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much! finally I develop a python CGI based solution, a bit more static than I thought but meets the expectations of the team.

Greetings